# wxPython MainLoop and Quartz CGEvent events on a separate thread trigger an illegal instruction error

Tags: python, wxpython, core-graphics, keyboard-events, macos-catalina

I'd like to understand the reason for the failure I'm seeing with wxPython and Quartz events on macOS Catalina and python 3.8.1.
Here's a minimal python script

```py
import Quartz
import threading
import time
import wx

def press_key():
    time.sleep(10)
    Quartz.CGEventPost(Quartz.kCGHIDEventTap, Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 6, True))
    Quartz.CGEventPost(Quartz.kCGHIDEventTap, Quartz.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, 6, False))

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        worker = threading.Thread(target=press_key)
        worker.start()
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.Show(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

Here wxPython event loop runs on the main thread, and a separate thread posts Quartz CGEvents.
When a CGEvent is posted, the script crashes with Illegal instruction error.

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Could someone help me understand what causes the error?  A simpler test, where CGEvents are posted on a separate thread, but no wx.App.MainLoop() is running, works without errors.